importing tablesaw library using maven for java
I am new to navigating intellij, Java projects, and Maven. I thought I did all the steps to import a dependency using Maven, but still getting errors. In other cases, the import tech.tablesaw is greyed out in a way as if it comments them out.
in my main.java file:
package org.example;

import tech.tablesaw.*;
import tech.tablesaw.aggregate.*;
import tech.tablesaw.io.csv.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
       Table table = Table.read().csv("people.csv");
       table.print();}}

in my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>tablesaw2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.tablesaw/tablesaw-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.tablesaw</groupId>
            <artifactId>tablesaw-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.43.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

I get this error regarding the library not being found/imported. I have a .csv in the project folder, but I don't get the the point of having import issues, it's not finding the tablesaw package

multiple imports get greyed out automatically from intellij?


Does restart of IDE helps?

I didn't try that originally, but I just did a few times and same issue. IDK why the other import lines get greyed out by intellij. I guess I can get this setup on another PC and see if I get different results.

There are couple of problems regarding your question. Let's address them seperatly.
First of all, I can see from the line import tech.tablesaw.api.* you succesfully imported the library. If you didn't, Intellij would throw you an error. But you are calling the read method wrong. read is a method belong to the Table class, not an object. So you need to call it like this:
Table.read().csv("people.csv");

instead of:
Table.read.csv("people.csv");

Second, the greyed out imports means that you are not using those imports in the current file. This is not an error or a warning that shows you did not import the library. So no problem there.
And finally, when i tried to import the library and run your code it gave me this error:
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.

So I suggest you provide a concrete java logging library on your classpath. More on here if you would like to know the details. So if you get this error line too all you need to do is add these dependencies to your pom.xml and you should be fine.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.16</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

Hope this helps.
